# Pull not working - TortoiseGIT / Windows 7 / GIT on Debian + gitolite

Tags: gitolite, tortoisegit, git-pull

i have a weird issue. Im using TortoiseGIT (Win7) and my repositories are placed on a vritual server (Debian), where im using gitolite and SSH keys.

I can `clone` the repository to my PC, i can run `Fetch`, `Push`, `Commit`, `Sync` .. everything, but when trying to `Pull` the changes from server `Pushed` by other contributor, the following error appears:

```
git.exe pull -v --progress      "origin"
fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-pull is broken?
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

I don't understand, why just the `pull` command is not working .. thanks for any help.

I can make a clone of the repository, with the contributed changes .. but can not `Pull` the changes to created repository on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very much linked to Git, and comes from [`help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/help.c#L286):

```c
static const char bad_interpreter_advice[] =
  N_("'%s' appears to be a git command, but we were not\n"
  "able to execute it. Maybe git-%s is broken?");
```

That is similar to [issue 40](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/issues/detail?id=40) (of another GUI, here [terminal-ide](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/)).

In that case, it was due to the remote Git installation, which was **incomplete**

([Comments 3 of issue 19](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/issues/detail?id=19#c3))

> git-merge was also missing from install, can be fixed with

```
$> ln -s git git-merge
```

> in `system/bin/`

The resolution might not be *exactly* the same in your case, but it could be related to a faulty Git installation.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the only thing i did on my virtual server, was the componen update (maybe it helped). now it is working fine. i dont know what was the issue, but i really appreciate your help. i will save your answer for future.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this same issue after changing the git Bash executable sh.exe to be always run as administrator (to get round another problem). It then left git unable to access it under certain scenarios and caused various "Maybe git-* is broken?" errors. Perhaps this might help someone...

Comment: I can't thank you enough! That was a very non-obvious solution, your answer probably saved me hours. Even reinstalling msysgit didn't help, apparently Windows was firmly attached to that setting even if the executable itself was removed.

Comment: I assume this error message might have many fathers, but your answer solved it for me.  Just want to make sure that this answer gets some attention for those who fell into the same trap myself and sundar.

Also, it was happening in Git Extensions for me, not TortoiseGit

Comment: Mine kept working and suddenly stopped, but this was the issue.

Comment: This works for me but is there a definitive solution?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling old Git and reinstalling the latest build fixed this issue for me.

Here's a link to the installers
[Link to get installers](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git)

My exact error message was

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-pull: line 304: exec: git-merge: not found
fatal: 'pull' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-pull is broken?
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're able to run "git fetch". If you can also run "git merge", running the  sequence "git fetch" followed by "git merge" will accomplish the same thing as "git pull".

Source:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Comment: Run `git config --global merge.defaultToUpstream true` to really mimic `git pull`'s behaviour